# How to load an image without ImageView from description which i get dynamically?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I don't want to use `ImageView` to display text because i may get any number of url links with some texts from back end

```
 "description": "<p>This is description</p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><img src=\"https://stagecmsbmncapi.projectpresent.biz/media/bulk_media/pool.png\" /></p>\r\n<p><img src=\"https://stagecmsbmncapi.projectpresent.biz/media/media/Street_hawking_is_now_the_trend_for_young_entrepreneurs_in_Terengganu_ioiuq38.jpg\" /></p>",
```